# How can I find the font "Proxima N W15 Reg"

Tags: html, fonts, webfonts

I have seen a font that I really like on the sendgrid.com site. The font is:

"Proxima N W15 Reg"

Here's a link to a page that uses it:

[An example page using the font](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html)

But I cannot find out anything about this font with google. Does anyone have any ideas where I could search for this font?

Comment: https://typekit.com/fonts/proxima-nova

Answer (score 0):

They are available on MyFonts, TypeKit, Fonts.com and a myriad of other websites, as a quick search will show.

Slightly more edgy, they are downloaded along the webpage you're directing to, as `woff` files, as the Web Inspector of your web browser will show you.